# Transformations in the plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

Please Note: I understand how the addition and multiplication of complex numbers work. I'm just  little confused by the wording in the book.

I am looking at *Visual Complex Analysis* by Needham. It seems to me that everything is backwards. For example, this is the geometric definition of multiplication:

> [image]

My problem is that we are rotating the plane. So suppose that I want to multiply $(2, 0)$ by $1 \angle \dfrac {\pi}{6}$. If I follow the directions and rotate the plane, this is what happens:

[image]

Here the black lines constitute the original plane, the blue dot is $(2, 0)$ in the original plane, and the red lines constitute the plane rotated by $\dfrac {\pi}{6}$. As we can see, the coordinates of the blue point with respect to the new axes are $\left(\dfrac {\sqrt3}{2}, -\dfrac 12 \right)$ when they should in fact be $\left(\dfrac {\sqrt3}{2}, \dfrac 12 \right)$

I have a similar problem with translations. The book says:

> [image]

I start again with the number $(2, 0)$ and I want to add $\dfrac 12 + i \dfrac 12$ to it. So I shift the plane by $\dfrac 12 + i \dfrac 12$, and this is what I get:

[image]

So clearly, I am following these definitions "backwards". But going word by word I don't see how I am misinterpreting the text.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ) may be relevant.

Comment: I agree that the author could have worded it better. What he means by a transformation of the plane is an action on _each_ point of the plane, leaving the axes fixed.

Comment: In your diagrams, you left the point fixed and applied the transformation to the axes instead.

Comment: @quasi Ah ok, that makes more sense; the author did say something about an action on each point, but he never said anything about the axes. Please see the first passage again, I have edited the question to include the text above it. But then, when we are multiplying $z$ by $a$, why do we have to rotate every point in the plane by the angle of $a$? Why don't we just stop after rotating $z$?

Comment: As @quasi says, it’s not the axes that are rotated, but the individual points. So the point $1=1+0i$ gets rotated to $cos\pi/6+i\sin\pi/6=\sqrt3/2+i/2$.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to transform all points of the plane if you're only doing one multiplication by $a$. But the action of multiplying by $a$ does the same thing to all points of the plane (by which I mean, applies the same transformation).

Comment: @quasi Ah ok thank you very much!

Comment: I guess I thought "plane" was defined as the points along with the axes, but I guess the plane is just the points.

Comment: Right, all clear now.